# Could/ should we add an answer-ranking system beyond standard votes?

Tags: feature-request, answers, voting

I just ran into a "problem" that I have encountered many times while on the various Stack Exchange websites.

After I came across an interesting question and read a good answer, I upvoted the answer. Then, I read another answer and thought it was way better (or other times, way worse) than the previous answer. It didn't make the previous answer any less worthy of an upvote, but it should still take precedence over the first one.

So, I was wondering if we could add a feature where we could rank answers 1-3 and award points to each answer accordingly. Like, 1 point for 3rd, 2 for 2, and obviously 3 for 1, or some other method.

I have no idea what kind of computer wizardry this would take, or if it's even possible; I also don't know if the community would want this. I see we recently added a feature reminding people to be nice to new users (which is awesome), and it made me think of this.

Comment: A [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) is one way to reward an exemplary answer that is worthy of more than just an upvote.

Comment: How about the 4th and subsequent answers? (e.g. case on [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12177/25183))

Comment: It is always a good idea to [be nice to people for a change](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnI62dsOKDo&t=1m5s).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No, thank you**

I respect what you're asking for, but if you think it through, you're asking for two things:

1. A way of promoting the best answer to the top of the list.
2. A way of rewarding respondents for their efforts to answer questions.

Stack Exchange is designed for the former, not the latter. Reputation is a means of motivating users to participate and to improve user skills on the Stacks,<sup>1</sup> but that motivation is not meant to clutter the primary goal of the service, which is to provide specifically useful answers to well-asked questions through the process of community curation and moderation.

As it is, some stacks (maybe most stacks) already have problems with up/down voting being used to express *popularity* rather than *usefulness* or *highest quality.* Burdening the system with even more voting power would only act to muddy the water further.

*Though I haven't read anything from SE Staff to suggest it, I wonder if one of the problems SE is facing is how to balance the goals of the service with its obvious value as a social platform. None of us want users to feel bad, but if we simplistically choose to assuage their feelings over the desire for quality questions and answers then the purpose of SE is undermined.*

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *I'd like to make an additional point here. I wonder if too often we don't encourage new users to learn good Stack Exchange skills early enough. We don't want to drive away new users, certainly. But there isn't a perfect way to train new users to SE's business and operational models while avoiding the inevitable hand-slap that's necessary during the training process (down votes, question closure, answer deletion, comments suggesting their <s>baby is ugly</s> question or answer could use improvement...). Reputation is, I believe, meant to be the carrot for participating both in terms of quantity and quality. If I'm right about that, then handing out up votes for every answer you like is actually a disservice. But, that's just my opinion.*</sub>

Comment: Up-votes are sometimes used as pity votes to offset (justifiable and usually necessary) down-votes, which ... defeats the purpose. I often wonder if the ability to expand the score to show +/- shouldn't be rep-based and in fact when there are down-votes they should be more prominent than up-votes are net score - all the time.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I think pity upvotes would do less harm [if answer downvotes were free](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421868/839601)

Comment: @gnat hard agree.

Comment: Points well taken. I agree.